# JQuery, check for arrow key pressed swith statement

Tags: jquery, switch-statement, arrow-keys

I've setup a keydown function and I want to do different things depending on whether the left, right, up or down arrow keys are pressed. That's working using a switch statement, but I'd also like to do something when ANY arrow key is pressed, but can't figure it out. My code:

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) {

var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which,
    arrow = {left: 37, up: 38, right: 39, down: 40 },

switch (keyCode) {

    case arrow.left:
        // do something left
    break;

    case arrow.right:
        // do something right
    break;
}       

});
```

I would really just like a line of code where I could check for whether any arrow key is pressed, but can't figure it out, so for example:

```
case arrow:
    // do something for any arrow keys
break;
```

Just using "case arrow doesn't seem to work. Could anyone help?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Thanks for your help everyone. Here's my final code, for anyone looking:

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) {

    if (e.which >= 37 && e.which <= 40) {
        $('p.key-notification').fadeOut('slow');
    }

    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which,
    arrow = {left: 37, up: 38, right: 39, down: 40 },

    switch (keyCode) {

        case arrow.left:
            // do something left
        break;

        case arrow.right:
            // do something right
        break;
    }       

});
```

Comment: `case arrow.left:
    case arrow.right:
    case arrow.up:
    case arrow.down:
        // do something for arrows
    break;`

Comment: This would either never be executed, or always executed instead of each specific arrows code block in a `switch` statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why does that also have to be within your `switch` statement?

Make a separate `if` statement after your switch:

```
if (keyCode >= 37 && keyCode <= 40) {
    // run your code here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I used this one, although I had to use "e.which" to check which key was pressed, as "keyCode" was returning no value, not sure exactly why?

Answer (score 2):

A single `switch` statement isn't able to match on multiple conditions - you can have fall-through, but that doesn't evaluate the expression on subsequent cases and won't achieve your desired effect. I'd do it like this:

```
if (keyCode >= 37 && keyCode <= 40) {
   // do any processing for _any_ arrow key here if it should happen
   // before individual arrow key processing

   switch (keyCode) {

      case arrow.left:
        // do something left
        break;

      case arrow.right:
        // do something right
        break;
   }

   // do any processing for _any_ arrow key here if it should happen
   // after individual key processing
}
```

Putting the `switch` inside the `if` statement saves evaluating it when none of the cases would've matched. (So obviously if you later wanted the `switch` to handle other keys you'd need to move it out of the `if`.)

If you needed to do something similar for keys that didn't have consecutive key codes then obviously you couldn't use a `>= && <=` condition so you'd do something like this:

```
if (keyCode === arrow.left || keyCode === arrow.right
   || keyCode === arrow.up || keyCode === arrow.down) {
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you needs if I understand you correctly.

**Another approach that adds to readability**

```
var  arrow = { left: 37, up: 38, right: 39, down: 40 };
```

**Any of them**

```
switch (evt.keyCode) {
    case arrow.right:
    case arrow.left:
    case arrow.up:
    case arrow.down:
        // Do something
        break;
}
```

**One of**

```
switch (evt.keyCode) {
    case arrow.right:
        // Do right
        break;
    case arrow.left:
        // Do left
        break;
    case arrow.up:
        // Do up
        break;
    case arrow.down:
        // Do down
        break;
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for your response, that makes it very neat, too!